# Javascript checking variable is null showing results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript function for a button. When the button is clicked, it will display information. I'm trying to check if there are no results in the current set and go to the next set of results.

```
$("#mybutton").on("click", function() { 
    var $rowsNo = $("#table tbody tr").hide().filter(function () {
        var $checkresults =  $.trim($(this).find("td").eq(0).text()) === "1";

        if ($checkresults  != null){
            return $.trim($(this).find("td").eq(0).text()) === "1"
        } else
            return $.trim($(this).find("td").eq(0).text()) === "2"
    }).show();
});
```

This solution only seems to still be capturing the first option only and displaying null data. is there a better way to handle this type of scenario?

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: And the question is....?

Comment: console.log($checkresults) in between declaration and the if, and make sure it's actually null.

Comment: this solution  always seems to result to the first case which is null never passing through to the second. is there a better way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that uses `data-*` attribute and jQuery's `.data()` method

```js
var $rows = $("#table tbody tr");

$("[data-showrow]").on("click", function() {

  var showrow = $(this).data("showrow"); // Get the data value: "", "1", "2" etc
  if (!showrow) return $rows.show();     // if "" was clicked, show all and exit.

  $rows.hide().filter(function(){
    return $(this).find("td").eq(0).text() == showrow;
  }).show();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-showrow="">All</button>
<button data-showrow="1">1</button>
<button data-showrow="2">2</button>
<button data-showrow="3">3</button>


<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td> <td>Lorem</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td> <td>Ipsum</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td> <td>Dolor</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td> <td>Sit</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td> <td>Amet</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td> <td>consectetur </td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td> <td>Adipiscing</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```